# Zoom in camera viewport

Tags: 3d-view, camera

As you can see in the picture in the camera the red bordered rectangle is what the camera sees. How can I zoom in to this rectangle without changing the camera viewport/settings.

[image: Display]

Comment: Scroll the mouse up or use *zoom camera 1:1* option, or press Home. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/is-it-possible-to-view-the-scene-in-the-viewport-camera-view-at-11

Comment: Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8842/is-there-a-way-to-align-camera-to-view-and-fit-the-view

Comment: From that view just press `Home`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scroll wheel, it exist a short cut that is somthing like klick+Shift+Ctrl or klick+Alt+Ctrl and drag.
In the N menu remove lock camera to view.