# What happened to my camera and how to set it back to default?

Tags: camera

[image]

My camera became all distorted and if I add a different camera, it does the same thing.

Comment: I would recommend making a habit of saving a new version every time you are done with something or just haven't saved a version recently so you can go back or import an earlier version of an asset (mesh, material e.g.)

Comment: It's all simple. You zoomed out camera view. Make sure that Properties shelf > Lock Camera to View is not enabled and zoom back in. Or use shortcuts from View menu, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/is-it-possible-to-view-the-scene-in-the-viewport-camera-view-at-11

Answer (score 0):

The sensor size is the zoom and focal length is what it sounds like. you can use Shift + F to move it in first person.

The problem is that the default isn't same for everyone or every scene so it is hard to say what it is in your case.