# Why my "Match the camera to 1:1 to the render output" (shift + numpad-enter) shortcut doesn't work?

Tags: shortcut

I'm looking at shortcuts in version 2.79b, specifically:

- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>numpad-enter</kbd>
- which calls `view3d.zoom_camera_1_to_1`
- and [is supposed to](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.zoom_camera_1_to_1) "*Match the camera to 1:1 to the render output*"

When in camera view, and "Lock camera to view" option is on, I can zoom or dolly the camera with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>MMB</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>MMB</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>numpad-enter</kbd> doesn't do anything though (laptop with azerty layout and external numeric keypad).

1. I read: [Is it possible to view the scene in the viewport camera view at 1:1?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15650/15265) but the question is dated 2014 and the explanations seem not relevant in current version.
2. From the comments and answer so far, changing the number of pixels in the render settings should allow for the effect to be seen. But it's not the case:
   [image]

**My questions are (for version 2.79b)**:

- How do we use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>numpad-enter</kbd>?
- Why it doesn't work on my configuration?

Comment: Look through the camera (Numpad5), press Shift NumpadEnter. It works for me as described.

Comment: @Leander. I assume you mean (numpad-0). It works for you "as described"... described where? So that I can understand what is the intention. To me it does nothing apparent (azerty keyboard, and external numeric keypad, in case that has some influence).

Comment: Shift NumpadEnter works exactly as described in the linked question. The answer is still valid and not obsolete/deprecated.

Comment: @Leander: That's not working on my side, question updated with a screencast. Now it *seems* (thanks Martin Z) this could be a keyboard problem. The screencast tends to go in that direction (key identified as Enter, not Numpad-Enter). [Targus](https://www.amazon.com/Targus-Numeric-Keypad-Black-AKP10US/dp/B002NURRL0) usb keyboard

Comment: If the answer is different I think you should answer your own question with details, so that it remains for others who might have the same issue to see.

Comment: @MartinZ: It's your suggestion of using the menu which helped find an answer, so it's ok (and fair) if you provide the answer. However if you don't want to, then I'll post one. Anyway, thanks a  lot.

Comment: No worries. Glad I helped you to reach the answer. I did not provide it though so it is yours to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I initially didn't understand what was the purpose of the shorcut, as nothing was happening. After some exchanges on the site, [Martin Z](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60759/martin-z) suggested to check whether the menu option (View | Navigation | Zoom Camera 1:1) did show the same problem. It didn't, the menu option worked as expected.

**Confirm the problem is with the shortcut**

This is an indication of a potential keyboard problem, and for those suspecting something similar:

- Confirm the shortcut is really the one you think. You may look at the menu entry or use <kbd>space</kbd> to display the search window. The shortcut will be indicated near the description of the function.
- If the shortcut is the one expected, then try running the function using the menu. If it doesn't work better, then the problem is elsewhere.

**Keyboard problem confirmed... what is the cause?**

In my case I use a laptop and an external USB keypad. The problem is the keypad, which brand is [Targus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002NURRL0):

[image]

I don't know whether this device doesn't generate the correct key code for key Enter, or whether Blender developers didn't bother or weren't able to differentiate the internal keyboard Enter from the USB keypad Enter, but in Blender API both keys appear the same.

**Workaround**

The solution is to change the shortcut associated with the function. It's done in user preferences (open this window with the combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (or menu entry File | User Preferences in the "Info" header).

Select Input tab and type a part of the function name, for instance "1:1" in my case, in the search field to display the function and its binding:

[image]

- Put the mouse pointer over the keyboard shortcut
- Press Enter to activate the key recorder
- Type a new shortcut, in my case <kbd>crtl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> to prevent overwriting one already in use.

Don't forget to save the user preferences, else the new binding will be lost when Blender will be closed.