# Ctrl+Alt+numpad0 problem

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

Whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> from *User Perspective*, the camera comes very close, which makes it hard to render what I want.

How can I render the very image that I am looking at?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/is-it-possible-to-view-the-scene-in-the-viewport-camera-view-at-11